# Откуда пошло «ну такое (себе)» и когда оно, наконец, исчезнет?

Tags: грамотная-речь, общие-вопросы, идиомы

Заранее извиняюсь за эмоциональную подачу вопроса. Надоело просто это слышать из каждого утюга. День ото дня всё сложнее что-то посмотреть или почитать в Интернете, не наткнувшись на эту глупую, безграмотную, ничего не выражающую фразу. Да и в устной речи всё больше людей зачем-то начинают её употреблять. Скорость её распространения напоминает настоящую эпидемию. Но почему? Как объяснить, что люди разных возрастов так охотно заменяют нормативное «так себе» на это неуклюжее и нигде не зафиксированное выражение? Почему говорить неправильно оказывается для многих таким приятным запретным плодом?

В ответах я предлагаю обосновать, почему же это выражение безграмотно, а также поделиться прогнозом о том, что ждёт эту фразу в будущем: она всем надоест, или же через несколько лет, смирившись, авторы начнут включать её в словари? [Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D1%83_%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5), пусть он для грамотного человека и не имеет веса, уже успел её зафиксировать. Значит, для многих далёких от русского языка фраза уже будто бы "официальная".

Comment: Может быть, скобки убрать? Или в них есть смысл?

Comment: Употребляют и с "себе" и без. Поэтому скобки.

Comment: Мне нравится «такое себе». Это в меньшей степени оценочное суждение и в большей про свои ощущения. А это более прогрессивное и экологичное выражение мнения)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не обращал внимания конкретно на это выражение, поэтому не припомню, чтобы слышал его. Но вот здесь его отнесли к *подростковому сленгу*:

https://teenslang.su/content/%D0%9D%D1%83%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5

> Характерно для речи людей, у которых слов не хватает для точного,
>   ясного, яркого выражения своих мыслей. Им трудно подобрать
>   прилагательные, словосочетания для описания предметов, явлений,
>   событий, вот они и используют паразитическое выражение «ну такое».

Это очень правдоподобное объяснение. На определённых этапах развития речи грамматические формы усваиваются постепенно. Например, в английском языке дети (носители языка) сначала усваивают времена неправильных глаголов (что требует простого запоминания), затем интуитивно образуют герундии и уже позже научаются образовывать временные формы правильных глаголов. Так и здесь вероятно, что на каких-то этапах развития речи (которые у некоторых могут  следовать с задержкой), подростки испытывают затруднения в подборе слов и останавливаются на чем-то нестандартном, но похожем на речь взрослых. С подростками же общаются люди самых разных возрастов. Часть этих людей оказывается "в телевизоре", и пошло-поехало. Распространению подобного способствует эффект **подражания**. Когда-то, лет 10-15 назад, из агрессивных политических ток-шоу в речь массового обывателя и многих публичных личностей, включая дикторов и даже некоторых литераторов, перекочевало корявое употребление выражения "в том числе". Поначалу его просто путали с выражениями "в частности" и "в числе прочего" (тоже от недостатка словарного запаса), позже стали вставлять куда попало, как "мусорное" словосочетание, по аналогии с уже ушедшим "как бы". Оно даже стало заменять ответ "да" на вопрос, требующий подтверждения, или употребляться на всякий случай, как аргумент (мол, у меня в запасе есть ещё что сказать).

Comment: Смотря какое _ну такое_. Важна интонация. Если это хезитативное _ну такое_, то действительно слова не подбираются, а если впору сказать _ну такое_ и покачать ладонью и головой, то это уже самодостаточная оценка. У вас односторонний ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, что причина в том, что выражение «так себе» похоже на наречие, и просится вопрос «Как?».

— *Как ты спал?*
— *Так себе.*

— *Как сдал экзамен?*
— *Так себе.*

«(Ну) такое (себе)» похоже на прилагательное, и просится вопрос «Какое?»

— *Какое у тебя настроение?*
— *Такое (себе).*

Поскольку мы чаще описываем не действия, а объекты, то прилагательное удобней.

— *Как тебе фильм?*
— *(Ну) такое (себе).*

Кроме того, использование среднего рода ко всему подряд, как бы лишает объект оценки значимости, важности.

— *Как тебе моя новая машина?*
— *(Ну) такое (себе).*

«Себе», я думаю, опускают, чтоб звучать более непринуждённо, подальше от официального литературного языка, скованного правилами, чтоб не сочли за «ботаника».

Я слышал и видел без слова «Ну» в начале, просто «такое». Однако слово «Ну» тоже может иметь смысл.

По словарю Ушакова у «ну» есть значение:

> частица. В реплике, содержащей условное допущение, вынужденное
> согласие, употребляется в значении допустим, положим, что так
> (просторечие).

«Ну» в начале, я думаю, добавляется для придания оттенка вынужденности дать хоть какую-то оценку. Чтоб ещё больше лишить объект оценки значимости, важности.

Существует так же версия, что это выражение возникло в Интернете, потому что смартфоны автоматически заменяли при наборе слово «так» в «так себе», на «такое». И адресаты сообщений, часто получая это словосочетание, не распознавая ошибку набора, стали считать это нормой.
Хотя я лично не замечал таких исправлений. Интересно, другие замечали? Напишите.

Comment: "Атомически"? Или всё-таки "автоматически"?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Спасибо, исправил.

Answer (score 0):

Мое мнение об этих двух словосочетаниях субъективно. Оба они являются оценкой с признаком низкого качества. И оба имеют окрас сомнения и брезгливости.

**Так себе** - словосочетание отвечающее на вопрос *как?* Применяется при **оценке объекта**.

> ***Как** он (объект) на твой взгляд?*
>
> ***Так**... **себе** (не всем) сойдёт.*

---

**Такое себе** - словосочетание отвечающее на вопрос *какое?*. Применяется при **оценке действия**.

> ***Какое** оно (действие) на твой взгляд?*
>
> ***Такое**... **себе** (не всем) можно.*